# Take SQL input in PHP and output query results to the page

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I'm looking to create a page using PHP that will take SQL input, and output the results returned by the DB (MySQL). This is not for a production website (I understand the security implications). It's more for learning and practice. Kind of like the SQL console section of phpMyAdmin, or even similar to what sqlzoo.net can do (I think they are using perl, but I'd like to do it in PHP). Is there a practical way to accomplish this?

For example, how can I create a page in PHP/HTML to display a table of results when I don't know how many columns the query will return?

Also, what is the most practical way to allow a visitor to this web page to restore the DB to a default state with the original data? (e.g. create a sql dump of the original state and make a button that runs it? or is there a better way?)

Thanks!

Comment: check the source of phpmyadmin

Comment: Haha interesting idea although I'm sure the source is large enough that finding this specific code would be difficult enough, much less comprehending it. Not looking to rip off their code completely either although I would be curious to see how it is accomplished. Have you done this?

Comment: no, but I worked on projects with source which is at least 100 or 1000 times larger so.. I guess it takes about 2-5 minutes to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` in your SQL query to fetch all columns and loop over the results from [mysql_fetch_row()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) or [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) with `foreach`.
Besides that, have you thought of using the mysql CLI ? It's useful for those requirements.
This question should be more specific than it is now.

"create a sql dump of the original state and make a button that runs it?" - Yes. But make sure you drop/delete the existing data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually I've used the CLI as well as the SQL input box in PhpMyAdmin.. and for practical purposes those work great. As a learning exercise, what I'm trying to do is make a page in PHP that emulates the functionality of those resources.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to run at least two queries... first return one row using LIMIT 1, and count the returning elements (using PHP count($row) if you use mysql $row = fetch_row($handle) ) to count the columns, and you can use SQL COUNT() to find out how many rows would be returned.

As for returning data to original state, I think a drop/recreation from a dump like you said may be the simplest and most reliable option.

Comment: you don't need two queries for checking the number of columns

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is just running the query, checking if the amount of rows > 0, and then if it is, loop through the query resultset in a foreach and just show whatever you like.